# std::thread causes program to abort

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, abort

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <thread>
int main(){
    std::thread trial([](){ return 2;});
    //trial.join()
    return 0;
}
```

From this I get the following output:

```
terminate called without an active exception
[1]    17963 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Now, this doesn't happen when I call `.join()` after I create the thread. As far as I know, `.join()` waits until the execution of the thread ends. However, it also seems to prevent abort from happening. Could somebody explain what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could somebody explain what's going on?

From the documentation of the destructor of `std::thread`:

> If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), `std::terminate()` is called.

In the example, you failed to join the thread, therefore it is joinable when it is destroyed, therefore the process `std::terminate()` is called. By default `std::terminate()` calls `std::abort`.

If you do join, then after the join, the thread will not be joinable. Therefore `std::terminate()` will not be called upon the destruction.

Comment: In C++20 there is [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) which joins upon destruction instead of terminating the program